# Can you tell me which method should be called in inheritance in java?

Tags: java, oop

```
   Class A {
    dog()
   }
   Class B extends A {
    cat()
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    A obj1 = new A();
    B obj2 = new B();
    A obj3 = new B();
   }
```

when `class A` object is created then obj1 will call `dog()`,when`Class B`'s object is created then obj2 will call `cat()` and `dog()`.but `A obj3= new B()` is created which method should be called?please answer
Thanks

Comment: This code will not compile for many reasons. Please [edit] your question to correct it. Also use `{}` button from editor to properly format your code.

Comment: Also when you are done with correcting your code try executing it and you will know the answer. To find *why* it happened try searching for *polymorphism* and especially *dynamic binding*.

Comment: There is only one method on A called `dog` so this is the only method you can call on a reference to `A`

Answer (score 2):

To give a quick and dirty answer, from what I think you mean:

Both methods CAN be called. (In your example, neither method WILL be called because, excluding the other errors, you aren't actually calling any of the methods)

I won't get fully into polymorphism but I will try my best:

If you have:

```
Class A {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Bark!");
    }
}
```

and

```
Class B extends A{
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Meow!");
    }
}
```

and I do

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj1 = new A();
        B obj2 = new B();
        A obj3 = new B();

        // And you want to see what happens when you do:
        obj1.doSomething();
        // Prints Bark!
        obj2.doSomething();
        // Prints Meow!
        obj3.doSomething();
        // Prints Meow!
}
```

Notice that the important thing here is that BOTH classes have the exact same name for the method, even
though it does different things!

That is the (I think) key concept to polymorphism you are trying to understand: You
can redefine what a method does in a subclass! HOWEVER, to redefine a method, the method has to have the same
name! Then, the compiler will pick the version of the method that is defined at the lowest level.

In your example

```
Class A {
    public void dog() {
        System.out.print("Dog!");
    }
}
Class B extends A {
    public void cat() {
        System.out.println("Cat!");
    }
}



public static void main(String args[]) {
    A obj1 = new A();
    B obj2 = new B();
    A obj3 = new B();

    obj1.dog()
    // This is the only method class A has, as that is what you defined. It will print Dog!
}
```

However, B defines its own method, called `cat()`. So you can do `b.cat()`.

BUT DON'T FORGET: B also extends A, so what A has, B also has.

So you can also call `b.dog()`!

`obj3` since it is linked to a `new B()` can call both `dog()` AND `cat()`.

If they were named the same thing, obj3 would call the version of the method defined in `class B`.
 However, in your case, they are two seperate methods, one is NOT overriding the other.

To answer your question.

If we return to my code, calling
     `A obj3 = new B();`

```
obj3.doSomething();
// Prints Meow!
```

This is because we defined `obj3` as a `new B()` so it takes on the method `doSomething()` in they way `class B` defines it.